# Finding and creating Symmetric Matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, symmetric-matrices

Given the matrix, find symmetric closure of it. I am having a hard time understanding how to solve this.
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0&0\\1&1&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0\\1&0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}

my try

[ 0 1 1 1 1

1 0 1 0 1

1 1 1 1 1

1 0 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 0]

Answer (score 1):

Taking the symmetric closure of a relation just means adding the smallest set of ordered pairs to the relation so that the result is symmetric. So for the matrix representing the relation, this is really equivalent to adding the fewest number of $1$'s so that the resulting matrix is symmetric, i.e. setting $A_{i,j} = 1$ wherever $A_{j, i} = 1$. This yields:

\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&0&1\\
1&1&0&1&1\\
1&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&0&1\\
1&1&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: So weird, so I updated my try. I am way off tho!

Comment: Is the trace of my original matrix 2?

Comment: From  what I understood, we add edges in the opposite direction.

Comment: That's true. For symmetricity, $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$. This is always true for the diagonal elements. For the non-diagonal ones, if $a_{ij}=1$ then so should be $a_{ji}$. That is, if there is an edge from $i\rightarrow j$ but not from $j\rightarrow i$, you add the latter to your relation. In general, the symmetric closure of a matrix $A$ is $A\vee A^T$. Note that the trace of a matrix and its symmetric closure is the same.